# Parsing jsp and JSON Array

Tags: jsp, arrays

I have a servlet that creates a List of objects and send it to a jsp file. This file should show the whole list of objects using JSONArray (it will be read by an android application, so i must use JSONArrays). I started some days ago reading guides on how to parse the text to be read in JSONArray but I totally fail. This is an example of what I need to do.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>{
<%List<Object> list = (List<Objects>) request.getAttribute("object");
for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++)
%>{
        "Title" : "<%= object.getTitle()%>",
        "Content" : "<%= object.getContent()%>"
},
<%
}
%>
```

The question is: how can I get a complete list of objects, displaying them using JSONArray format? How can I write "If this is the last element, don't display " }, " but display only " } "?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor, and

- don't use a JSP to do that. Generate the JSON array in the servlet
- use a JSON library to transform your Java object into a JSON array. There are plenty of those libraries available for free. See http://json.org

Now, to answer your Java programming question:

```
if (i == list.size() - 1) {
    out.print("}");
}
else {
    out.print("},");
}
```

Comment: I use Gson to format the list inside the servlet:
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(objectlist);
out.print("{");
out.print(" \" list\" :");
out.print(json);
out.print("}");

But I get an error while reading it from my android application, saying: 
05-29 08:28:24.128: W/System.err(655): org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head><title>Apache of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

What am I missing?

Thank you really much for the answer!!

Comment: Invoke the URL from a browser. I suspect it's generating an error page.

Comment: From the browser it works. I see a complete list of my objects, parsed in JSON. Like: "[{"title" : "titleofobj1", "content" : "contentofobj1"}, and so on

Comment: Use "View page source" on your browser and make sure it ONLY contains the JSON array. Your android app received a page which starts with <html><head>... which is obviously not JSON.

Comment: Found it, there was a typo error inside my servlet!! Now it's fixed!!
Thank you for your patience and your time!! :)